# Generate variables with fixed $R^2$ and coefficients

Tags: r, regression, r-squared

I have a random variable `X`.

```
set.seed(1)
X <- rnorm(10,0,30)
```

I would like to generate three other variables `(y1, y2, y3)` that have a pre-specified R^2 of `.50`, `.36` and `.26`.

i.e: `cor(x,cbind(y1,y2,y3))^2=0.5,0.36,0.26`

and also the coefficients for a linear model where y1 y2 and y3 are regressed on X return:

`0.4, 0.25 and 0.1`,

i.e.: `lm(X~y1+y2+y3) -> 0.4*y1 + 0.25*y2 + 0.15*y3`

Is this possible to do starting from X?

Comment: I indicated a duplicate that addresses what you *seem* to ask for.  In fact, though, you are demanding something that is mathematically impossible: by definition, `diag(cor(cbind(X,y1,y2,y3))^2)` will have only $1$s as components--try it!

Comment: I think the OP meant to ask `cor(x,cbind(y1,y2,y3))^2=0.5,0.36,0.26`, in which case the question makes sense: how to satisfy the $R^2$ constraint and the regression coefficient constraint at the same time.

Comment: I corrected the first point. But I don't think the linked 'duplicate' addresses my question. I'm asking about two contraints at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this in two steps.  First, generate random vectors $y_i$ and remove the projection of each $y_i$ onto $x$, leaving just the orthogonal component.  This will leave each $y$ uncorrelated to $x$.  In R, this can be done like this:

```
Y<-matrix(rnorm(30),10,3)
Y<-Y-lm(Y~X)$fitted
cor(X,Y)
##              [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
## [1,] -2.11488e-18 -9.71395e-20 -6.33554e-18
```

Then normalize each $y_i$ so that it has variance $1$, and add a normalized multiple of $\sqrt{\frac{r}{1-r}}$ of $x$ back in, to achieve the desired correlation:

```
r<-c(0.5,0.36,0.26)
Y<-apply(Y,2,function(x) x/sd(x))
Y<-Y+outer(X/sd(X),sqrt(r/(1-r)))

cor(X,Y)^2
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]  0.5 0.36 0.26
```

Finally, for the regression coefficients, note that multiplying $y_i$ by $c$ will result in the corresponding regression coefficient being multiplied by $1/c$, without affecting the correlation matrix.  So we can satisfy this constraint simultaneously as follows:

```
beta<-c(0.4,0.25,0.15)
Y<-Y %*% diag(lm(X ~Y)$coef[-1]/beta)

lm(X ~ Y)$coef
## (Intercept)          Y1          Y2          Y3 
##    3.966083    0.400000    0.250000    0.150000 

cor(X,Y)^2
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]  0.5 0.36 0.26
```